# How do I remove the title frame in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to completely remove the frame title from Emacs to get something like writeroom in my `org-mode`. I'm already using [`darkroom-mode`](http://www.martyn.se/code/emacs/darkroom-mode/) but I still have the frame title.

I tried

```
(setq frame-title-format nil)
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

---

**EDIT**

Turns out that what I am really after is removing the *mode line*. I found the solution in the manual:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format nil)
```

Comment: Here a presentation of writeroom :  http://www.maclawstudents.com/blog/product-reviews/writeroom/     With emacs, you can have exactly the same thing for free by using darkroom + the line I put above!!

Answer (score 3):

If i got you correctly

```
(setq frame-title-format "")
```

worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what I meant was in fact that : (setq-default mode-line-format nil)

Answer (score 1):

These days there is also [`writeroom-mode`](https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode),

> a minor mode for Emacs that implements a distraction-free writing mode similar to the famous Writeroom editor for OS X.

It hides *all* GUI components, including the mode line and the title bar.

It is available on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) and can be installed via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `writeroom-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> (provided that MELPA has been [added to the `package-archives` list](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa#usage)).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is fullscreen mode.  It's not available in mainline Emacs AFAIK,
but you can build you own patched version from homebrew.

See this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/256404/fullscreen-emacs-in-osx